# Power function of a test,example

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, normal-distribution, statistical-inference

Consider a population with the pdf $N(\theta,1)$ where $\theta$ is unknown and hypothesis
$H_0:\theta=5.5$ and $H_1:\theta=8$.Suppose that $\bar{X}=\frac{1}{9}\sum_{i=1}^9 X_i.$Reject $H_0$ iff $\bar{X}
>7.5$.Power function is given by $Q(\theta)=P_{\theta
}(\cal R).$ $\beta=P{\text{(type-II error)}}=P({\text{Accepting } H_0}$ when $H_1 \text{is true}).$

**Why then** $Q(\theta_1)=1-\beta$ and $Q(\theta)=1-\Phi(22.5-3\theta)?$

In particular how arises $3$ in front of the $\theta$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have some undefined non-standard notation in your question.
I gather that the power is $P(\bar X \ge 7.5 | \theta = 8) \approx 0.9332.$

If so, in order to evaluate the probability you can use:
$$P(\bar X > 7.5) = P\left(\frac {\bar X - \theta}{\sigma/\sqrt{n}} > \frac{7.5 - 8}{1/3} \right) = P(Z > -1.5) = 0.9332,$$
where the result is obtained from printed tables of the standard normal CDF.

Alternatively, you could use software or a statistical calculator. From R statistical software we get:

```
1 - pnorm(7.5, 8, 1/3)
## 0.9331928
```

Below are graphs of the densities of $\bar X$ (based on $n = 9$ observations)
for $H_0: \theta = 5.5$ (blue) and $H_a: \theta = 8$ (brown). The power
is the probability under the brown curve to the right on the vertical
line at $7.5.$ A better choice for the critical value would have been
something near $6.75$: then probabilities of both Type I and Type II error
would be essentially $0.$

[image]

*Note:* You asked about the `3`: I believe it is the square root of the sample size.

Comment: I do not understand your second line: why $P(\bar X \ge 7.5 | \theta = .8) \approx 0.9332.$? Should be $\theta=8$ here and not $0.8$?

Comment: Also, do you please have some link to standartization $$P\left(\frac {\bar X - \theta}{\sigma/\sqrt{n}} > \frac{7.5 - 8}{1/3} \right)$$? I.e. how $${\sigma/\sqrt{n}}$$ arises there?

Comment: (1)  .8 is a typo, which I shall fix. Thanks. (2) The variance of the sample mean is $Var(\bar X) \sigma^2/n,$ so its standard deviation is $SD(\bar X) = \sigma/\sqrt{n}.$ The SD is used in the denominator when standardizing.